# gsutil requires python 2.6 or 2.7. Issue

Tags: python, gsutil

I was using **gsutil** API to connect to `clusterdata-2011-2` (which is a Google cluster-usage traces of 29 days). it was worked perfectly. But after I have installed `Anaconda3`, it does not work anymore.

It says that `gsutil` requires `python 2.6 or 2.7`. 
Even after adding an alias in `.bashrc`

> alias python='/usr/bin/python2/'

It didn't work

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your alias is wrong firstly...

alias python=/usr/bin/python2.7

Feels better.

Check your PATH i.e. $PATH

And try and Remove the Anaconda part...

Answer (score 0):

euh it  didn't work
but also i don't want to remove Anaconda cause i am working with it..
i am thinking about deploying a new VM ware machine without installing neither python3 nor anaconda

Thank u for your suggestion !!